# cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to Find Username by userId

this code snippet working

```
Discussion_CreateBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(discussion.CreatedBy).UserName,
```

and this once not working in following controller class

```
Comment_CreateBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(c.CreatedBy).UserName,
```

this is my model classes

```
public class DiscussionVM
{
    public int Disussion_ID { get; set; }
    public string Discussion_Title { get; set; }
    public string Discussion_Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Discussion_CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Discussion_CreateBy { get; set; }

    public string Comment_User { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CommentVM> Comments { get; set; }

}

public class CommentVM
{

    public int Comment_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Comment_CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Comment_CreateBy { get; set; }
    public string Comment_Description { get; set; }

}
```

this is whole controller class

```
    public ActionResult Discussion_Preview()
    {
        int Discussion_ID = 1;

        var discussion = db.AB_Discussion.Where(d => d.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID).FirstOrDefault();
        var comments = db.AB_DiscussionComments.Where(c => c.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID);



        DiscussionVM model = new DiscussionVM()
        {

            Disussion_ID = discussion.Discussion_ID,
            Discussion_Title = discussion.Discussion_Name,
            Discussion_Description = discussion.Discussion_Name,
            Discussion_CreateBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(discussion.CreatedBy).UserName,
            Discussion_CreateDate = discussion.CreatedDate,

            Comments = comments.Select(c => new CommentVM()

            {
                Comment_ID = c.Comment_ID,
                Comment_Description = c.Comment_Discription,
                Comment_CreateBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(c.CreatedBy).UserName,                    
                Comment_CreateDate = c.CreatedDate

            })

        };



        return View(model);
    }
```

Getting following error

> Method 'Project.Models.AspNetUser Find(System.Object[])' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Project.Models.AspNetUser]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Project.Models.AspNetUser]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Discussion_CreateBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(discussion.CreatedBy).UserName
```

Works because discussion is an in-memory object because you are executing a query by calling `FirstOrDefault` on it:

```
var discussion = db.AB_Discussion.Where(d => d.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

On the other hand in the following statement:

`db.AspNetUsers.Find(c.CreatedBy).UserName`

`c` is not queried yet because

```
db.AB_DiscussionComments.Where(c => c.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID)
```

returns an `IQueriable` and not the actual collection of comments

The easiest way to fix it is to bring all your comments into memory (since you are anyway need them all) :

```
var comments = db.AB_DiscussionComments.Where(c => c.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID).ToList();
```

Comment: as you said I chaned that code snippet ,  then what should I refer for code snippet does it change also `Comment_CreateBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(c.CreatedBy).UserName`

Comment: The only change you need to do is : `var comments = db.AB_DiscussionComments.Where(c => c.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID).ToList();`

Comment: you're genius thnks lot